# How to check if npm packages installed in the app have vulnerabilities?

Tags: javascript, npm, sonarqube

I have a React Js app and I will like to know if the npm packages installed and third-party libraries have vulnerabilities. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run [`npm audit`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit).

From the docs:

> Scan your project for vulnerabilities and automatically install any compatible updates to vulnerable dependencies