# How to check vulnerabilities of a third-party library use in a React JS app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, sonarqube

I have a create-react-app and I add some scripts to use a third-party library how can I check if those libraries have vulnerabilities?

Comment: Hi @Fernando, maybe "npm audit" is what you are looking for...
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if npm packages installed in the app have vulnerabilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63256685/how-to-check-if-npm-packages-installed-in-the-app-have-vulnerabilities)

Answer (score 4):

You could use `npm run audit`. It is a security audit command, which will alert you of any found vulnerabilities - in your `node_modules`, `package.lock` & `package.json` (You can choose from many flags in that command)

Read more about it [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit)

If you are injecting with `<script>` tag itself, I would recommend trying to find the `npm` module for it and installing it that way, so you can keep track of everything at once with `npm run audit`. If that is not the case, I suppose you could find a vulnerability scanner on google, but I am not so familiar with them to write on their accuracy.